# Passport JS, values on error redirect are blank

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using the standard passport local strategy (with express.js) for the signup form on my website. When the `failureRedirect` is invoked, it redirects back to my signup form correctly, but all the values of my form are wiped blank.  I get why this is happening, because of the redirect, but ... This is incredibly annoying for the user if they've made a simple mistake like forgetting a checkbox or their username is already taken. (Also, I know the password should not be sent back to the view).  Is there a way to persist the users entered values even after the redirect with passport?

```
//my route
.post('', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    failureRedirect: '/account/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
}), function(req, res) {
    ...
});
```

passport code

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    }, function(req, username, password, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            if(password != params.password2) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Passwords do not match.'));
            }

            User.findOne({
                'username': username
            }, function(err, user) {
                // if there are any errors, return the error
                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'That username is already taken.'));
                } else {
                 ... create a new user ...
                }

            });

        });

    }));

    function(req, username, password, done) {
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you wrap passport in your route logic. For example,

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  // Do something here with the username & password, like
  // checking if the username is available.
  if (!username || !password) {
    // Render the login form, and pass in the username and password.
    res.render('/login', {username: username, password: password});
  } else {
   // If all is validated, attempt the login:
   passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
     failureRedirect: '/account/signup', 
     failureFlash: true
   }), function(req, res) {
     ...handle response here...
   }
  }
});
```

I'm not sure if all of that is syntatically correct, but the idea is to do whatever application-specific validation you have to do before you attempt to authenticate with Passport.

Comment: I guess this would work, but it doesn't seem like as nice/clean of a solution as I was hoping for.  To me it seems like a failure "middleware" that gets passed the `req` obj and errors would work perfectly.  Then you could keep all your authentication and validation logic in a single place.

Comment: While I agree that it would be nice to handle both validation and authentication in one place, I think the purpose of Passport is to provide authentication only, and to leave validation up to you. On the [GH page](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) for passport, the first sentence is "Passport's sole purpose is to authenticate requests"... While there are hooks for failures, I don't think validation falls into that scope.

Comment: But validation is built into the strategies.  If you leave out the username and password, you get the "Missing credentials" error.

Comment: Yes, there is some validation (missing username & password), but if you want it to do what you are talking about (storing the username and password), it (1), needs to be compatible with all the strategies (Local, Facebook, Google, etc), and (2) the "user" details are completely different as well (which results in different callback signatures). Above, you are using a Local Strategy - compare that with the Google and Facebook strategies, which handle the response differently.